# ReactJs Styled Components: Set Font Weight of Table Cell

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components, mui-x

Using React 18, and latest styledcomponents, how do I set the font weight for MUI Table Cell?

This code is getting the right color, but not setting font weight.

```
const StyledTableCell = styled(TableCell)({
  backgroundColor: "#99D9EA",
  fontWeight: "800",
});

<StyledTableCell>Enrollment Date</StyledTableCell>
```

[image]

Comment: it will be very helpful if you can reproduce this issue in a smaller app on something like codesandbox so that you can share your code for testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
const StyledTableCell = styled(TableCell)({
  "& .MuiTableCell-head": {  // or "& .MuiTableCell-root" or "& .MuiTableCell-body" ...
    backgroundColor: "#99D9EA",   
    fontWeight: 800,
  }  
});
```

Possible CSS classes are described here: https://mui.com/material-ui/api/table-cell/

Comment: hmm doesn't seem to be working latest react version and mui

Comment: Look in the browser debugger to see what CSS classes are installed for your component.